# Вывод картинки (Mysql->title == названию картинке в папке.jpg) то echo картинку

Tags: php, изображения, foreach

**Создал картинки с названиями title из бд**

```js
<?php foreach ($products as $item){
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("img/$item->images");
    $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
    $font_path = 'E:\serv\OSPanel\domains\localhost\verdana.ttf';
    $text = $item->title;
    $text2 = $item->desc;
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 100, 400, $white, $font_path,$text2);
    imagejpeg($jpg_image,"img/$item->title.jpg");//сохранил картинки
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);
}
?>
```

Теперь хочу вывести в цикле картинки из папки,если title равен названию файла 
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: С чем помочь? Как сравнить два значения? С помощью `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас есть путь к картинке.

Тогда:

```
$path = 'С:\foder\file.jpg' 
$fileName = basename($path, 'jpg'); // берем им'я файла

if ($fileName == $item->title) { //cравниваем
 //код
}
```

Comment: Хочу сделать ссылку на файл. 
<code>
<?php
$dir = 'img/'; // Папка с изображениями

$name = $product->title;  //название файла Nokia
$atr = $product->atr;  //расширение файла .jpg

$files = $name . $atr; // Берём всё содержимое директории

$path = $dir.$files; // Получаем путь к картинке
echo "$path"; // Выводим ссылку на картинку
</code>

И у меня получается такое img/Nokia<b>img</b>.jpg
Лишняя img пристыковывается..

Comment: @Sergey У меня получилось по Вашому примеру все хорошо [Код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ca88cdfd3a933309c35c48b92967336650aa541) . Наверное у Вас в базе хранится сдесь **$product->title;** не просто **Nokia**, а **Nokia<b>img</b>**. Или в **$product->atr** хранится **<b>img</b>.jpg**